# Conversion error from date time to string format

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, sql-insert

I have a problem with this section of code, I'm trying to insert a record into my booking table. The values I'm trying to input are (6, 3, 3, 20/06/2018 00:00:00, 400, 2800.00, True, 560.00)

```
        public void insertBooking(int bookingID, int customerID, int entertainmentID, 
                                  DateTime bookingDate, int numberOfGuests, double price, 
                                  bool deposit, decimal depositPrice)
        {
            db.Cmd = db.Conn.CreateCommand();
            db.Cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Booking (bookingID, customerID, entertainmentID, 
                                  [Booking Date], [Number Of Guests], [Price], [Deposit?], 
                                  [Deposit Price]) " + "Values ('" + bookingID + "','" + 
                                  customerID + "','" + entertainmentID + "','" + 
                                  bookingDate + "','" + numberOfGuests + "','" + price + 
                                  "','" + deposit + "','" + depositPrice + "')";
            db.Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

The error I'm getting is as follows,

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string."

I have tried to research the problem as best I can but I can't figure out how to fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Learn to use parameters for your queries.  Don't munge queries with string constants.

Comment: And the fix to your problem and to SQL Injection is always the same. Use Parameters

Comment: Sorry should have said they are parameters, the values I said i was inputting are just examples

Comment: Have you tried bookingDate.ToString("O")?

Comment: @ConorCasey those are not sql parameters. What we are telling you is to use the Parameters collection of the Command object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Comment: Your code takes the date format set in the machine where it runs. There are only two possibilities, input the date in the same locale format or explicitly set the locale for your application. From the test data, i assume it is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss, check is it the same date setting in your machine

Comment: @Steve oh right my bad, I understand what you mean now, Thanks for the advice but Kzrystof's answers worked for me anyway. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, you have a few issues on your code. I will try to explain all of them in order.

First of all, if you use `DateTime` values with string concatenation (on `+` operator), `.ToString` method automatically called for them and you get may or may not "proper" textual generated for your database column. [Do **not** choose wrong data types for your columns](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). You need to pass your `DateTime` value **directly**. If you don't know, which [SqlDbType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype) you know for your values, you can read the [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-types-net-framework/mapping-clr-parameter-data?view=sql-server-2017) also.

As suggested on the comments, best way to solve this kind of situations is using [parameterized queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). On the other hand, these string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to dispose your connection (which we don't see but..) and commands automatically instead of calling [`.Dispose` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose) (which you didn't) manually.

As an example;

```
public void insertBooking(int bookingID, int customerID, int entertainmentID,
                          DateTime bookingDate, int numberOfGuests, double price,
                          bool deposit, decimal depositPrice)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Booking (bookingID, customerID, entertainmentID, 
                            [Booking Date], [Number Of Guests], [Price], [Deposit?], 
                            [Deposit Price]) Values(@bookId, @cusId, @entId, @bookdate, @guests, @price, @deposit, @depositPrice)";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@bookId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = bookingID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cusId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = customerID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@entId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = entertainmentID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@bookdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = bookingDate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@guests", SqlDbType.Int).Value = numberOfGuests;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = price;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@deposit", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = deposit;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@depositPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = depositPrice;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this has cleared up all my issues, relatively new to SQL so not 100% with all the typical conventions, but I'll definitely be using the Parameters function from now on. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To fix the error, use `bookingDate.ToString("O")`.

That being said, it is not considered a good practice to build your SQL query like that. As mentioned in the comments, it is recommended that you [use the `Parameters` property of your `SQLCommand` instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server comes with the following data types for storing a date or a date/time value in the database:

- DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD.
- DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.
- SMALLDATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.
- TIMESTAMP - format: a unique number.

  ```
  DateTime your_datetime_instance = DateTime.Now;
  var str = your_datetime_instance.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
  ```

Comment: Well that's just wrong. SQL Server does not store display format for any date or datetime data type. It can implicitly convert strings of specific formats into datetime and datetime2 - and these formats are either culture-specific or ISO 8601 - so for dates use either `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyyMMdd`, and for datetime - `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`. Please note that omitting the `T` from the DateTime format will make the string representation of the Datetime value culture specific if you are converting to DateTime, but not if you are converting to DateTime2.